# Two paragraphs in the same line

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put two `<p>` in the same line? I've tried setting the `margin` to 0, put it still won't work. Does anybody have an answer to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have both paragraphs `display: inline-block;` That way you can set their respective widths.

Comment: display:inline on both, use grid, flex, float, etc etc etc

Comment: This makes no sense. Why use paragraphs if what you actually want is something else. Can't you use a span?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive with your issue?  If you are looking to display two pagragraphs, you would wrap them each in paragraph tags i.e: `<p>Paragraph 1</p> <p>Paragraph 2</p>.  Screenshots may help?

Comment: You know what a paragraph *is* right? Why wouldn't you use two `<span>`s or something along those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `inline-block`s are for. Assign `display: inline-block`  and a width less than 50% to the paragraphs to get the desired result

```css
.myclass {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<p class="myclass">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
</p>
<p class="myclass">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph `<p>` tag is a block level element where as the span `<span>` tag is an inline level element.

If you want to make the paragraph tag inline you may do this:

```css
p {
display:inline;
}

.spacer-text {
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:5px;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div>Two paragraph tags:</div>
<div><p style="color:olivedrab;">Voilà! In view, a humble vaudevillian veteran, cast vicariously as both victim and villain by the vicissitudes of Fate. This visage, no mere veneer of vanity, is a vestige of the vox populi, now vacant, vanished. </p><p style="color:rebeccapurple;">However, this valorous visitation of a by-gone vexation, stands vivified and has vowed to vanquish these venal and virulent vermin vanguarding vice and vouchsafing the violently vicious and voracious violation of volition.</p></div>

<div class="spacer-text">A nicer approach would be two spans:</div>
<div><span style="color:firebrick;">The only verdict is vengeance; a vendetta, held as a votive, not in vain, for the value and veracity of such shall one day vindicate the vigilant and the virtuous.</span><span style="color:peru;">Verily, this vichyssoise of verbiage veers most verbose, so let me simply add that it's my very good honor to meet you and you may call me V</span></div>
```

Comment: While you're technically correct, your example is horrific. Please improve it.

Comment: I added the V for Vendetta quotes for my text and changed the color to hipster rebeccapurple and peru @Martin

Comment: Ahahaha While I **do** appreciate that effort; what I meant was that inline CSS styles is *not* the way to code anything.